# Why do we set the attribute type of images to Binary Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

All my images are assorted in the app and managed by the asset catalog. I don't understand why in order to create a Core Data Stack with images I have to set the attribute type to Binary Data, XCode knows the name/string of each image. Why can't the attributes be a `Transformable` type or even a `String`?

Comment: Definitely, you can achieve using a transient property, that loads the image for you from a path stored in CoreData.

Comment: You **don't** have to do that, and `Transformable` is a reasonable choice. What leads you to think that you must use a binary data attribute?